# Error input in form HTML running in the browser Iceweisel (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, regex, html, browser

Why is this browser allowing me to type these characters `[ ' ~]` beyond the numbers ? How can I solve this?

The image of my problem is here: 
[image]

On Google Chrome this works:

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]" name="points">
```

allowing only enter numbers, but iceweisel ( firefox) not.

Comment: The answer is on the image you provided. 

"Depending on browser support : Numeric input will apply on the input field." 

There's **NOTE**

Comment: I know . But this was my attempt to solution this problem, after that I tried to listen the keypress event and too not work.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, IE does not support that field type. It's as simple as that.

If your question is how this problem can be overcome, then one solution is to take a more verbose Javascript approach. Once the user submits, or leaves the field, grab its value with JS, check it, and show an alert to the user if it is wrong. You should also check it server side if it is important. Patterns are not yet a secure way of **guaranteeing** user input - only really providing input hints to the user.

You can also look at [Polyfills](http://html5please.com/#number), which can replicate new functionality in old browsers.